# Do I need a user@mydomain.com email for sending emails using Mailgun?

Tags: email, mailgun

I am currently using **Mailgun** for sending emails. I have verified my domain and entered all the records correctly.

I am using **laravel** which provides an easy way to use **mailgun** for sending emails.

I have given a `MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS` as a gmail address eg.

```
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=user@gmail.com
MAIL_TO_ADDRESS=myaccount@gmail.com
```

But this is not working at all. The **Mailgun logs** shows email is delivered but no email is received in my gmail inbox at eg. **myaccount@gmail.com**

So is it because my `MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS` is a **gmail address** and not a **domain email address**?

Comment: Is the Mailgun account in Sandbox mode by chance?

Comment: No. I have added and verified my new domain

Comment: If the from email address is a google one it may be google blocking it as they will not recognise the sender. Try sending an email to a non-gmail address and see if that works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way that I've always used mail gun is that when you are in your mailgun account and click on the domain.  I use the  Defualt SMTP Login (under Domain Information) and that is my MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS
Here is a snippet from my code that may or may not help you.  In this example I'm using a blade template for the email.

```
try {
    Mail::send('hostconfirmationemail', ['client' => $event->client,  
                                           'user' => $event->user], 
        function ($mail) use ($event) {
            $mail->from('postmaster@yourdomain.com', 'Mail Room');
            $mail->to($event->user->email)->subject('New Lead Seminar RSVP Confirmation');
    });
} catch (\Exception $e) {
   return $e->getMessage();
}
```

Comment: It works...But is postmaster@yourdomain.com allowed to be used for production or is it just for testing purpose.

Comment: @Raj postmaster@yourdomain will work for production.

Comment: I tried using support@mg.yourdomain.com and it also works. So I guess as long as I keep mg.yourdomain.com at the end I can send from any email address. Am I right?

Comment: I believe that is correct.  I use postmaster cuase it sounds official.